# how can I set tab order on every Component in html without use tabindex?

Tags: html, model-view-controller

How can I set tab-order on every Component in html without use tabindex? This means each time I press tab, I will focus on the next one component.

A negative example:

```
<h1 tabindex = "0">hello world</h1>
<h1 tabindex = "1">second</h1>
<h1 tabindex = "2">third</h1>
```

this works well, but can I want to pass on all elements without saying that every component will be defined under the tabindex.

thank you very much

Comment: @acostela I did it, I'd love to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting it up dynamically via JavaScript

Heres a **Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/ZbXbda

`$("h1").each(function (i) { $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1); });`